# New to cloth simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation

In the past few days I've been learning how to do cloth simulation in Blender. One of the issues I'm having is when I render the animation with the cloth simulation enabled. It stands still as a solid object,then  it twitches weirdly. There have been no videos that fixes this issue.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bake simulation before rendering. It can be done from cache tab:

[image]